# Proper way to create path with specific permissions

Tags: c, path, mkdir

Developing in C language, I would like to write a function that create a path with specific permissions using the function `int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode)`. I'm not interested in a solution that just works (that, I know how to do), I'm interested in a **proper** solution, a solution of good practice.

My questions are the following :

### How to properly handle the umask and the mode in order to have the permissions requested ?

I thought of two solutions :

```
int create_path(char *pathname, mode_t mode, mode_t umask_wanted)
{
    mode_t old_mask = umask(umask_wanted);
    mkdir(pathname, mode);
    umask(old_mask);
}
```

Or

```
int create_path(char *pathname, mode_t mode)
{
    mode_t old_mask = umask(0);
    mkdir(pathname, mode);
    umask(old_mask);
}
```

Or creating a different function for different masks in order to ensure that the user of the function is really aware of what he does.

Or something else ?

### How to properly handle the creation of a full path ?

Here is a piece of code that shows a solution but it might be quit naive.

```
int create_path(char *pathname, mode_t mode)
{
    int i;
    char* path = malloc(strlen(pathname) + 1);
    if (path==0)
    strcpy(path, pathname);
    for(i=0; path[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (path[i] == '/')
        {
            path[i] = '\0';
            mkdir(path, mode);
            path[i] = '/';
        }
    }
    free(path);
}
```

Is this solution of good practice? or any better idea?

### How to handle the permissions when a part of the path already exists?

Should we change the permissions of the already existing folders in order to fit the mode specified?

Or should we change only if it gives more permission?

---

Note : Those pieces of code are just examples to illustrate my questions. For the solution, I would manage errors of `mkdir` and mix all of that in one function.

Note2 : I assume the user of the function knows what he does and what exact permissions he needs ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't we move that question on codereview ?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post.